# iOS: Attributed String Renders Differently on iPhone 6S, Simulators and iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel, rendering, nsattributedstring

I have a `UILabel` that I have put a white backgroundColor to highlight the text, which renders perfectly fine on the simulators and my iPhone device. However, when my friend installs the very same app through a distribution portal, the font is unacceptably crispy - like almost there was no font smoothing. Also the background opacity is very different than what I see on my device.

Here's the example snippet that sets title text's attribute:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func _setupUI() {
        let textTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.title)
        let highlightColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.7)

        textTitle.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor, value: highlightColor, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textTitle.length))

        // self.textTitle --> UILabel
        self.textTitle.attributedText = textTitle
    }

    _setupUI()
}
```

And here are the rendering differences, screenshots taken from my device on left (iPhone 6S), and another device on right (iPhone 7) at the same time:

[image: Screenshots]

The font is Helvetica, although I tried Roboto as well, which resulted with the same issue. I have also tried moving the `_setupUI` to different methods such as `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`, but nothing changed. App was removed and re-installed completely on iPhone 7, but the problem still persists.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Check if you have some sort of scale set on the UILabel or check if you have rasterization turned on, on the label's layer..

Comment: Are the iPhones running a different version of iOS or there any differences in any of the accessibility settings?

Comment: Log the value of the attributed string on both devices and see if there is any different in the fonts being used.

Comment: I've tried above steps: I've set / unset scale on UILabel's layer, rasterization on UILabel itself. Didn't work. Also printing the attributed text, I see the contents are exactly the same including fonts. iOS versions are different, up-to-date versus 11.0.3, but I don't believe that should have any effect.